# The requested resource [/] is not available

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to start my Spring MVC app using Tomcat 10, but I can't see html pages in browser.
I tried to use *http://localhost:8080/*, *http://localhost:8080/index.html/*, *http://localhost:8080/university/*, *http://localhost:8080/university/index.html/*

Can you help me? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

[image]

Here is controller:

```
package sk.viktorov.university.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

My WebConfig:

```
package sk.viktorov.university.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("sk.viktorov.university.controller")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public WebConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

Initializer:

```
package sk.viktorov.university;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
import sk.viktorov.university.config.SpringConfig;
import sk.viktorov.university.config.WebConfig;

public class MainWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

SpringConfig:

```
package sk.viktorov.university.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

@ComponentScan({"sk.viktorov.university.dao", "sk.viktorov.university.service", "sk.viktorov.university.validator"})
@PropertySource("classpath:university.properties")
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(@Value("${db.driver}") String driver, @Value("${db.url}") String url,
                                 @Value("${db.user}") String user, @Value("${db.password}") String password) {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(user);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public BufferedReader reader() {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }
}
```

And project tree:
[image]

Pom file. Sorry, it's big:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sk.viktorov</groupId>
    <artifactId>university</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>5.3.10</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>5.5.2</spring-security.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>4.0.1</javax.servlet.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.7.2</junit.jupiter.version>
        <log4j.version>2.14.1</log4j.version>
        <hamcrest.version>2.0.0.0</hamcrest.version>
        <mockito.version>3.12.4</mockito.version>
        <postgresql.version>42.2.23.jre7</postgresql.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.32</slf4j.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.200</h2.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.5</jacoco.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.20</lombok.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.12.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <bootstrap.version>5.1.0</bootstrap.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>CLASS</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.95</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/exception/**/*</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/domain/**/*</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/controller/**/*</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/dao/SpringJdbcConfig.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/ConsoleUniversityApplication.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/controller/HelloController.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/MainWebAppInitializer.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/WebConfig.class</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What is `projectname` in the URLs that you tried?

Comment: f1sh, *http://localhost:8080/university/*

Comment: How do you start the server and how do you deploy your project into the tomcat server?

Comment: try this http://localhost:8080/university/html/index.html/

Comment: f1sh, I use Intellij Idea and server Tomcat that I set up into the run configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. The problem is Tomcat 10 does not work with Spring 5. So, I will use Tomcat 9.